# Why does "ubuntu-bug" launch Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center, bug-reporting

I'm running a new install of Ubuntu 14.04.

I want to report a bug with the filesystem messing up when I wake it from sleep with a USB flash drive in it.

I try to run the "ubuntu-bug" program to file a bug report, but that command results in Ubuntu Software Center launching, which offers me new programs but seems to have no bug reporting feature. Why? Is that a bug itself?

Oh, and though this is a duplicate question with many old crusty answers, what should I do to report a kernel bug these days, if not fix(?) and use ubuntu-bug?

(I also tried to use the Ubuntu One web site, but despite it ironically saying it wants to give me one login for everything, it has apparently forgotten my password once again... I have a list of my past Ubuntu One passwords, none of which will it recognize. I seem to remember the last time I managed to get Ubuntu One web site to do anything useful, there was a new and an old version of the site or something, but I'm way out of patience trying to use that site.)

Edit: Oh, I see I can get ubuntu-bug to work if I use a terminal window. I was using the Ubuntu menu because an answer to another question had said to use Alt + F2 and type ubuntu-bug, which I thought I remembered used to work before I installed 14.04.

EDIT: OH! I see now - the Ubuntu icon just gives a search field which looks identical to the command field you get when you type Alt + F2, but is search not run. Thanks folks!

Comment: Ubuntu One has been discontinued.

Comment: @CarlH No it hasn't. Only file sync service and music store/streaming were discontinued. Ubuntu One provides the SSO system for Ubuntu.

Comment: @Dronz do you have a video of what happens when you run ubuntu-bug and it brings up software-center? I can't imagine any situation where it would do that.

Comment: @dobey I'd be willing to make one later today when I get home, if someone suggests a destop video capture tool for Linux - I've not done that before. Oh I guess I can use my phone... I'm just going to the search menu and typing ubuntu-bug, and the Ubuntu Software Center appears, nothing else.

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer based on that new information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run `ubuntu-bug linux` in a terminal to report a bug against the kernel. As *ubuntu-bug* is not a normal application itself, when you search for *ubunu-bug* in the dash, the first result will be *Ubuntu Software Center* and when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will be launched. To run *ubuntu-bug* from the dash, you will need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to bring up the run entry, and then you can type `ubuntu-bug linux` there to file a bug against the kernel.

If you are having some problem with that, you can go to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux to report a bug against the kernel.

Comment: Thanks, too bad that is also the bug. ;-) Actually I see ubuntu-bug linux does work if I use a terminal window rather than the Ubuntu menu. I was using it after following another answer which said to use Alt + F2 and then type ubuntu-bug.

Comment: I just tried it here, and it works exactly as I described. :)

Comment: Oh I SEE NOW... Alt + F2 looks the same as using the Ubuntu menu, but gives a run command which looks identical to the "search everywhere" control you get if you click the Ubuntu icon.